# Image manipulation through a local proxy

Tags: proxy, image-processing

I would like to run commands on images before they come to my browser. For example, I would like to compute the MD5 of the image, then decide whether I should pass it unmodified, pipe it through an image filter (blur it for example), or totally replace it with an image of the same dimensions (for example, a cat).

I have found a program called webcleaner but it does not seem to be maintained (since 2006) any more; it can be compiled under Ubuntu 12.04 using a [patch](https://github.com/janl/couchdbx-core/blob/ff47372552d10df00d74cb7989dfed4a19a6040d/patches/js/patch-jsprf.c) but it's using [runit](http://smarden.org/runit/index.html) and I can't find how to start it.

Comment: @Antoine [This](http://www.ex-parrot.com/pete/upside-down-ternet.html) will be a fun read! In other words: use Squid to have your script called on the request of an image.

Comment: @gertvdijk It would be really cool if you could write that out into a comprehensive answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question was answered in a comment (which [the OP indicated answered it](https://askubuntu.com/questions/130020/image-manipulation-through-a-local-proxy#comment304102_130020)), linking to an external source and summarizing its essentials:

> [This](http://www.ex-parrot.com/pete/upside-down-ternet.html) will be a fun read! In other words: use Squid to have your
>   script called on the request of an image.

– [gertvdijk](https://askubuntu.com/users/88802/gertvdijk) [2 days ago](https://askubuntu.com/questions/130020/image-manipulation-through-a-local-proxy#comment303930_130020)